# Qt: Respond to title bar proxy icon menu

Tags: macos, qt

On the Mac you can set the window title to a path or file and a "proxy icon" will be shown next to the last element of the path. For example, if you open a Finder window and control click on the title you can select a directory to switch to; in TextEdit you can perform operations on the file.

In Qt we can use `setWindowFilePath()` to set a proxy icon and the last section of the path. I can control click and get a menu with the different sections of the path going up to root.

How can I respond to the user selecting another directory on this menu ?

Is it possible to set a custom menu, the same as TextEdit ?